# Web Scraping: Error handling when web page doesn't contain any specific element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, try-catch

I've written a Python script for scraping pages for information like Phone Number, Address, Rating, etc. The script is running fine when all the values are available on the page. However, it throws error where there is no specific info like Phone Number is not available. It breaks the loop, what all I want is to skip those pages and continue scraping next pages.

Below is the sample code to extract phone number:

```
def get_phone_number(body):
i=0
for item in body.find('p',{'class':'contact-info'}):
    i+=1
    if(i==2):
        phoneNo=''
        try:
            for element in item.find_all(class_=True):
                classes = []
                classes.extend(element["class"])
                phoneNo+=str((which_digit(classes[1])))
        except:
            pass
        return phoneNo
```

Above is the function to scrape contact information. Below is the error that I'm facing in the for loop.

```js
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-bfd4a9d231f1> in <module>()
     20                 dict_service = {}
     21                 name = get_name(service_html)
---> 22                 phone = get_phone_number(service_html)
     23                 rating = get_rating(service_html)
     24                 count = get_rating_count(service_html)

<ipython-input-25-7168fec7d0c7> in get_phone_number(body)
     21 def get_phone_number(body):
     22     i=0
---> 23     for item in body.find('p',{'class':'contact-info'}):
     24         i+=1
     25         if(i==2):

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any sort of help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: Hi @Mitiku, I've just edited the entire error message that I'm facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are getting this error when you try to iterate over None object. 
This line

```
for element in item.find_all(class_=True):
```

will not be where the exception is raised because it has been handled. 
The possible line where this error might have occurred is outside of `try ... except` block. Most probably the following line

```
for item in body.find('p',{'class':'contact-info'}):
```

to handle this you should prevent iterating on NoneType.
You have two options.

Using `try.... except` block.

```
try:
    for item in body.find('p',{'class':'contact-info'}):
        i+=1
        if(i==2):
            phoneNo=''
            try:
                for element in item.find_all(class_=True):
                    classes = []
                    classes.extend(element["class"])
                    phoneNo+=str((which_digit(classes[1])))
            except:
                pass
            return phoneNo
except:
    pass
```

Using conditional branching

```
items = body.find('p',{'class':'contact-info'})

if items is not None:
    for item in items:
        i+=1
        if(i==2):
            phoneNo=''
            try:
                for element in item.find_all(class_=True):
                    classes = []
                    classes.extend(element["class"])
                    phoneNo+=str((which_digit(classes[1])))
            except:
                pass
            return phoneNo
```

Comment: How can I prevent iterating over NoneType? 
I also want to ignore scraping such pages where there are no elements with relevant information.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Mitiku, it worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @Mitiku, can you please have a look at this link?https://github.com/SaranshVatsa/Data-Scraping/blob/master/webscrapeExcel.py .......
Here is the script of scraping that I'm trying to scrape the data from the website. The problem that I'm facing is that the loop for scraping in the script is not executing even after couple of hours. The cell seems to be busy for execution in Jupyter Notebook for hours.

Comment: The second while loop(while loop inside for loop) is causing infinite loop. This is because you are updating  `i` for only those conditions you specified with `if ... elif`. You forget for else case. I suggest to move line to update `i` from the `if ... elif` block.

Answer (score 0):

find method does not return an iterable or list like object. You used use find_all method like

```
for item in body.find_all('p'):
```

Comment: Using find_all() doesn't extract phone number. It leaves the field blank and returns nothing.