# Beautiful Soup Error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' retrieving stock data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, stock

My goal is to sequentially fetch urls from an sqlite3 database and download quotes from a website. the unload routine for a single title, without iterative process works:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
input_str = input("Insert stock's url:")
if input_str=="":
    input_str="https://www.teleborsa.it/indici-italia/ftse-mib"
res = requests.get(input_str)
soup = bs(res.content,'lxml')
price = soup.find("span", class_="h-price fc0").text
print("Stock price ",input_str," è ",price)
```

Problems exist when I use an sqlite database that contains various urls. The sql querty is correct and the table is read but the following code gives an error:

```
# reading records
for row in rows:
    input_str=row[6]
    res = request.get(input_str)
    soup = bs(res.content,'html.parser')
    price = soup.find("span", class_="h-price fc0").text
    curdata =soup.find("div", class_="header-bottom fc3").text
```

Comment: Tried this code but it is not reproducible. `rows` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a test like below and everything was ok:

```
rows = list()
[rows.append("https://www.teleborsa.it/indici-italia/ftse-mib")
 for _ in range(5)]


for row in rows:
    input_str = row
    res = requests.get(input_str)
    soup = bs(res.content, 'html.parser')
    price = soup.find("span", class_="h-price fc0").text
    curdata = soup.find("div", class_="header-bottom fc3").text
    print(price, "\t\t", curdata)
```

first you missed an "s" using requests. and the problem is probably the part with the row[6]. make sure you are using correct URLs when retrieving them from database. if you want more help give us some of the database outputs pls.

Comment: Hi, i have done a demo to upload. In demo code works, i must think to a improvement code in gas of error retrieving data

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete code. For the only one record, code works. I must think to some incorrect urls.

```
    import sqlite3
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    import datetime
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
 
    # connessione
    con =   sqlite3.connect("/demo.sqlite")
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from tbLista")

    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    # preparo il foglio
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.delete_cols(1,2)
    ws['A1'] = "Isin"
    ws['B1'] = "Price"
    riga=1

    # lettura records
    for row in rows:
      riga +=1
      ws['A'+str(riga)] =row[4]
      ws['B'+str(riga)] =row[5]
      input_str=row[5]
      res = requests.get(input_str)
      soup = bs(res.content,'lxml')
      price = soup.find("span", class_="h-price fc0").text
      curdata =soup.find("div", class_="header-bottom fc3").text
      firstmod=price.replace('.','')
      secondmod=float(firstmod.replace(',','.'))
      ws['B'+str(riga)] = secondmod

   # chiusura
   cursor.close()
   wb.save("demo.xlsx")
   print("ok")
```

I don't write code about error management in soup

Comment: can you print out the row[5] and type(row[5]) and tell me the output?

Comment: from>>> rows = cursor.fetchall(), this output>>[(1, 1, 'JAN GLOBAL LIFE SCIENCES EUR', 'EUR', 'IE0002122038', 'https://www.teleborsa.it/fondi/janus-hend-global-life-sciences-a-cap-eur-hdg-jlifa1eu-ie0002122038-RkMuSkxJRkExRVU', None, None, None, -1)]>>>> the url works well, I need code to manage errors in url scraping....I see that>>>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940768/web-scraping-error-handling-when-web-page-doesnt-contain-any-specific-element